# How to center the favicon and title in a browser tab

Tags: html, css

I wondered how to center the favicon and title in a browser tab.

The basic code was

```
<title>center me please</title>
```

Then I attempt 3 times below:

```
 <center><title>Center me please</title></center>



 <title><center>Center me please</center></title>



 <title style="text-align:center">Center me please</title>
```

None was working though :(

Comment: I guess the only way is to use leading spaces?

Comment: use blank space &nbsp; between title tag

Comment: I insert &nbsp; before the content, but the space is not shown.

Comment: <title>&nbsp;&nbsp;center me please</title>, the browser ignores &nbsp somehow, anyone has ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `<title></title>` is for the `<head></head>` section of the HTML document.

**You can't add css style attributes to it.**

> Permitted content     Text that is not inter-element whitespace.

...

> The HTML `<title>` element defines the title of the document, shown in a
>   browser's title bar or on the page's tab. It can only contain text and
>   any contained tags are not interpreted.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title